# AppStore Error 102

Tags: macos, imac, mac-appstore, software-update, error

[image]

[image]

Hi everyone, as the title above, all updates are working smooth but suddenly when I'm going to update iTunes, it show the Error 102.

The picture in the attachment have the information of my iMac 2012.

I first thanks for the replying. Hope for y'all helping.

Comment: Before giving any solution, I would suggest you wait for a while. Sometimes when Apple Server get overwhelmed then it also gives 102 error for App Store. Is it still the same now for you?